# Aggregate query in MS-Access that calculates current and cumulative amounts by account is exceptionally slow

Tags: sql, performance, ms-access

I'm having trouble with an Access query. Although it runs , it is ***exceptionally*** slow; and I fear I may be overlooking a simpler, more elegant solution in my query design.

For context, I work in an accounts receivable office. We have thousands of customers, and each customer can have one or more accounts.  Every month, transactions post to the various accounts, and I am preparing the invoices for the customers. In my particular case, a customer's first invoice is always 001, then 002, and so on. We bill monthly.

To describe a *simplified* example, in month of January 2020, customer A may have the following transactions in the Transaction table:

```
+-----------------------------+
|TransID|Account|Amount|InvNum|
+-----------------------------+
|1      |1      |$10.00|001   |
|2      |2      |$5.00 |001   |
|3      |3      |$2.00 |001   |
+-----------------------------+
```

So, in the above example, I would want to issue invoice 001 to customer A for a total of $17.00, broken out by account.  The invoice would look something like this:

```
     +-----------------------+
     |Account|Current|ToDate |
     |1      |$10.00 |$10.00 |
     |2      |$5.00  |$5.00  |
     |3      |$2.00  |$2.00  |
     +-----------------------+
              $17.00  $17.00
```

Now, suppose that in February 2020, additional transactions post. A simplified version of the Transaction table would look like this:

```
+-----------------------------+
|TransID|Account|Amount|InvNum|
+-----------------------------+
|1      |1      |$10.00|001   |
|2      |2      |$5.00 |001   |
|3      |3      |$2.00 |001   |
|4      |1      |$3.00 |002   |
|5      |3      |$4.00 |002   |
+-----------------------------+
```

Invoice #002 issued to customer A would need to look something like this:

```
     +-----------------------+
     |Account|Current|ToDate |
     |1      |$3.00  |$13.00 |
     |2      |$0.00  |$5.00  |
     |3      |$4.00  |$6.00  |
     +-----------------------+
              $7.00   $24.00
```

The query I'm having trouble with is specifically designed to capture the month's activity by account **and** to calculate a cumulative total for the "ToDate" column on the invoice.  The challenge is that not every account will have transactions in a given month.  Note that account 2 did not post any transactions in February.  So invoice 002 has to show a current amount of $0.00 for account 2, but it also needs to know the cumulative amount ($5.00 + $0.00 = $5.00) for account 2.

The problematic query is itself made up of a few subqueries:

1. ***BillNumByAcccountQ***: an aggregate query that selects and groups all accounts by invoice number.
2. ***CurrentQ***: Also an aggregate query that selects and sums all the transaction amounts (from the transaction table), which is left-joined to BillNumByAccountQ. The left-join is necessary to ensure that there is a row for every bill number. The "Current" field in this query is given by the expression ***Sum(Nz(Amount,0))***. The result set of this query contains over 20K rows.

Finally, the problematic query is defined by the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
   Q1.Account
    ,Q1.InvNum
    ,Q1.CURRENT
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(CURRENT)
        FROM CurrentQ
        WHERE Q1.Account = Account
            AND Q1.InvNum >= InvNum
        ) AS ToDate
FROM CurrentQ AS Q1;
```

This query runs and runs and runs, and it eventually causes Access to stop responding. I do not even know how many rows it has because it never finishes running.  I fear that I'm overlooking a way simpler solution.

Apologies for so much information, and I appreciate any advice on simplifying this.

Comment: Please show the underlying SQL for queries: *CurrentQ* and *BillNumByAcccountQ*. Try to save *CurrentQ* as temp table and run final query off this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, doing a sub-query inside a select statement is slow, since it often needs to run the sub-query for every single row of the main query.

Doing the aggregation all at once is likely going to be faster:

```
SELECT 
     Q1.Account
    ,Q1.InvNum
    ,Q1.CURRENT
    ,SUM(i.CURRENT) AS ToDate
FROM CurrentQ AS Q1
JOIN CurrentQ AS i
     ON  i.Account = Q1.Account
     AND i.InvNum >= Q1.InvNum
GROUP BY Q1.Account, Q1.InvNum, Q1.Current;
```

In addition, if you're able to edit the database, you'd probably want to add indexes for the `Account` and `InvNum` columns.

Comment: Thank you! With a few minor tweaks, this solution really saved the day!  I've got a lot to learn about SQL and making it more efficient, and so your explanation of how the sub-query has to run for each row makes a lot of sense.